# Recover lost village without Google+

Tags: clash-of-clans

I got the code of my lost COC village, but I wasn't able to recover it because my Google Play services is outdated and I don't have enough internal memory to upgrade Google Play.

How do I recover a lost village, without using Google+?

Comment: Please use correct tags.

Comment: You should contact Supercell developers

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to open CoC without updating Google Play services, so pretty much your only chance is updating Google Play Services. Try removing a few apps.